# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que llegue el correo $from del remitente?

Tags: php, mail

Estoy usando un formulario de contacto básico en php que está funcionando:

```php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $to = "info@server.ar";
      $from = $_POST['correo']; 
      $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
      $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
      $subject = "Mensaje nuevo";
      $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " Escribió lo siguiente:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

      $headers = "De:" . $from;
      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
      echo "Enviado, gracias " . $first_name . 
           ", te contactaremos en breve.";
    }
```

Sin embargo el correo del remitente `De: $from` no funciona. El correo entrante que muestra es mi usuario de `cPanel @ misitio .com.ar` y lo que necesito es que llegue el correo de quien se contactó.

La solución que encontré luego de leer las respuestas fue modificar el código para dejarlo así

```
$from = $_POST['correo']; 
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject = "Mensaje nuevo";
$message = $first_name . "\n\n" . $last_name . " Escribió lo siguiente:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

// Nuevos encabezados
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
"From: <".$from.">\r\n".
"Reply-To: ".$from."<".$from.">\r\n".
"Date: ".date("r")."\r\n";
```

Comment: Revisa alguna librería como SwiftMailer, con la que podrás especificar una configuración smtp para enviar correos. Puedes ver como aquí: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/send-emails-in-php-using-the-swift-mailer--cms-31218

Answer (score 0):

El encabezado correcto es `"FROM: "` (no `"De:"`).

Además, es importante que tengas en cuenta que si la que se indica en dicho encabezado **no esta hosteada en el servidor que envia** puede que:

- El servidor de salida (*dependiendo de la configuración*):

  - Ignore el encabezado.
  - El mail no se envíe.
- El servidor de llegada:

  - El mail no llegue a la cuenta de destino o sea marcado como SPAM

### Solución:

Lo que se hace normalmente es utilizar el encabezado `"Reply-to: "` así cuando se responde al mail se responde a la cuenta indicada en dicho encabezado.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "info@server.ar";
    $from = $_POST['correo']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Mensaje nuevo";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " Escribió lo siguiente:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    // Nuevos encabezados
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".

    // AQUI - Reemplazar por datos cuenta en el server o eliminar
    "From: [NOMBRE_SISTEMA]<[MAIL_SISTEMA]>\r\n".

    // AQUI - Cuenta del contacto al que se va a responder
    "Reply-To: ".$first_name." ".$last_name."<".$from.">\r\n".
    "Date: ".date("r")."\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Enviado, gracias " . $first_name . ", te contactaremos en breve.";
}
```

Comment: Marcos pasó que sigue igual llega un correo que es mi user en cpanel, pienso que es una configuración del servidor; la novedad es que al darle reply carga $first_name $last_name en el campo del Roundcube donde va el Email

Comment: @XavierSal, eso es exactamente lo que intenté describir en mi respuesta. ¿Que le cambiarías para que se entienda mejor?

Comment: Si Marcos, primero gracias. Fuiste muy conciso en tu respuesta, aunque el exceso de información hizo que se me complique encontrar lo relevante a mi pregunta; yo luego de re leerte encontré que el problema estaba en este área "From: [NOMBRE_SISTEMA]<[MAIL_SISTEMA]>\r\n". // Reemplazar por datos cuenta en el server o eliminar

Comment: @XavierSal, he actualizado mi respuesta. Si te fue útil considera votarla y/o si responde tu pregunta considera marcarla como "aceptada". Mas info [¿que debo hacer cuando responden a mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @XavierSal Al estar en un entorno de cPanel te recomiendo que además de lo que ha contestado Marcos (¡recuerda aceptar su respuesta y no la pongas en la pregunta!) deberias cambiar esto: `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` por esto: `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, "-fCORREO@DOMINIO.COM");` en minúsculas. De este modo estas definiendo la cabecera `Return-Path:` que vas a necesitar para recibir los correos que por cualquier motivo cPanel no sea capaz de enviar. En caso contrario van a tu cuenta de cpanel `cPanel @ misitio .com.ar`.